# Ansible's docker_container module lacks support for cap_drop to restrict access to kernel caps

Tags: security, docker, ansible

I see ansible's `docker_container` module supports the "capabilities" parameter to add access to kernel capabilities for a container.

However it appears one can't restrict kernel capabilities further, for example with the earlier, deprecated "`caps_drop`" feature.

Given this, how does one restrict access to the kernel capabilities further than the default?

Looking at the ansible code:

"capabilities" is defined in `lib/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_container.py`:

```
 capabilities:
   description:
     - List of capabilities to add to the container.
```

However capabilities is the same as cap_add:

```
host_config_params = dict(
           …
           cap_add='capabilities',
```

The only mention of cap_drop is in the deprecated docker module (`lib/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/_docker.py`):

```
cap_drop:
  description:
    - Drop capabilities for the container.
    - Requires docker-py >= 0.5.0.
  type: bool
  default: 'no'
  version_added: "2.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this is not possible as of writing to drop capabilities in docker however there is an issue opened (http://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29578) that should be fixed soon as someone wrote a patch, for the mean time and if possible I'd suggest to use the old module.